# How to un-wrap code pasted into Emacs From StackOverflow

Tags: emacs

When I copy code from Stackoverflow and paste it into my emacs window, it pastes the whole thing as one super-long line, losing all the line-breaks. What's the easiest way to un-wrap this so I get back the line-breaks? Or paste it differently into emacs so it preserves line-breaks?

Comment: Operating system? Web browser? Emacs version? Does it still go wrong with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Windows XP, Internet Explorer, Emacs-22.3.1... did not try emacs -Q

Comment: The web browser should be another easy variable. Does the same thing happen with other browsers?

Comment: Why are linebreaks munched when you cut/paste code from a browser? Is the behaviour similar with other browsers and other editors like (say) notepad?

Comment: @Noufal good question -- I tried pasting from Stackoverflow on Internet Explorer into Notepad, and same problem, i.e. pastes as one huge line with no lineberaks. BUT when I cut/paste from Firefox, I have no problems. So it's not really an emacs issue, it's an IE issue. I may need to change some setting on my IE.

Comment: This exact issue has been addressed on Meta, I did not see it earlier:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11428/pasting-code-from-stackoverflow-to-notepad-loses-line-breaks-using-ie

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT:  I read this question too quickly --- the approach I outlined will help clean up a lot of things, but not OP's actual problem.  FWIW, I can't reproduce on the only windows box I have here]

Comment: Here is my specific situation: I pasted an E-lisp function into my .emacs buffer, which is in (Emacs-Lisp) mode. So I have my mode correct. I even tried selecting the region and doing M-x indent-region but no luck. (I am on Windows with Emacs-22.3.1)

Comment: Indent region will not introduce linebreaks (not usually anyway).